# Tkinter tag_lower "invalid boolean operator in tag search expression"

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to make a Tkinter window with a background image. I currently have:

```
master = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(master, width=WINDOW_SIZE_X, height=WINDOW_SIZE_Y)
count = 0

background_image = PhotoImage(file="NA.gif")
background_label = Label(canvas, image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
canvas.create_oval(40, 40, 700, 700, fill="red")
```

But when I run this, I don't see the oval (it's probably behind the `background_label`). If I add `canvas.tag_lower(background_label)` to just before when I create the oval, however, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FILENAMEHERE", line 206, in <module>
    canvas.tag_lower(background_label)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2587, in tag_lower
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'lower') + args)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid boolean operator in tag search expression
```

What am I doing wrong here and is this how I fix the issue of the background image covering everything else up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `place` to add a label with an image to the window. This will *completely cover* the canvas rather than being part of the canvas. Using `tag_lower` will have no effect because the background image isn't part of the canvas.

If you add the image to the canvas with the `create_image` method of the canvas, it will appear as a background image on the canvas.